# equation with text

Tags: equations

[image: Equation]

Here I have an equation but the text is too close to the fraction, how to solve this?
I used

```
\begin{equation*}
  \systeme{
 W_{ik} = \frac{R^2 - r_{ik}^2}{R^2 + r_{ik}^2}  if r_{ik}^2 \leq R^2,
 W_{ik} = 0  if r_{ik}^2 > R^2
  }
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `systeme` machinery isn't optimal for the job at hand. I'd like to suggest using a `dcases*` environment (provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{dcases*}
 W_{ik} = \frac{R^2 - r_{ik}^2}{R^2 + r_{ik}^2} 
     & if $r_{ik}^2 \leq R^2$,\\
 W_{ik} = 0  
     & if $r_{ik}^2 > R^2$\,.
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative can be:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{cases}
    W_{ik} = \frac{R^2 - r_{ik}^2}{R^2 + r_{ik}^2} & \text{ if } r_{ik}^2 \leq R^2\\
    W_{ik} = 0 & \text{ if } r_{ik}^2 > R^2
  \end{cases}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `amsmath` is not incompatible with `mathtools` – the lattter is an extension of the former.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I should have formulated it differently. But I think `dcases` is part of the extension and not `amsmath`. But I can be wrong.

Comment: It is indeed part of `mathtools`. Same for the starred version.

Comment: Thank a lots both of you!!!!